# How to cleanse 'emojis' from JSON file, before inputting into SQL

Tags: mysql, database, emoji, masking

I'm taking text fields from a JSON file and putting them into a MySQL database. SQL does not care for the emoji code \xF0\x9F\x98\x81 for instance. It says 'incorrect string value' when attempting to insert this data into a row.

I'm a bit out of my depth here, but I take it this is the UTF-8 code for an emoji, in this case the smiley face.

I'm using a java-based ETL client (Spoon by Pentaho) to take the JSON data and pass it to the MySQL database.

The thing is, I'm not sure how to write code to cleanse this. With Pentaho, I can use Java or javascript to attempt to fix this.

The JSON file, in browser, seems to render the emojis. Pentaho seems to write them all as a question mark (?) in output files ... HOWEVER, internally it seems to pass the actual symbol/ UTF-8 code, hence the error.

I'm confused because the java-based system is just passing around the UTF code '\xF0\x9F\x98\x81' .. correct?

Well actually no, it's not, because MySQL would gladly insert the string '\xF0\x9F\x98\x81' ... into any row, it won't insert a 'smiley face' or tiny man or whatever into a row ... so what is physically being passed, and how I can fix this with code? ... a bit confused, maybe I need to read up on UTF-8 here. I feel like there are two levels of data here ...

To make things more interesting, MS SQL seems to reference the symbol (upon attempted insertion and subsequent error) by it's UTF-16 code.

The question is, how I can reference this data in java/ javascript and destroy the emojis?

Comment: Do you have a data model and an insert statement (SQL level) which fails to add to this question?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I have a smiley emoji in a JSON file. My ETL software passes this into MySQL. MySQL doesn't support this character and throws an error. I need to prevent the emoji code from reaching the MySQL query.

Comment: I would like to see the failing SQL code to see why it fails since I do not see any reason why this insert would fail in the first place.

Comment: I resolved it but it's very basic issue - I wouldn't think too hard about it..... for example: insert into my_table values (1, 2, "hello", '')  .... mySQL responds 'error ... (UTF-8 code of emoji) is invalid for string column' .... it's just not supported. I found a javascript code that removes all these emojis with a regex expression

Comment: Ah, alternative for your answer (below): encode/decode of the data. That might keep the emoji

Answer (score 1):

alright ... was an easy fix...

if it helps someone else...

I used custom Java Script code I found elsewhere on Stack Overflow....

var new_custom_fields =
custom_fields.replace(/([\uE000-\uF8FF]|\uD83C[\uDF00-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDDFF])/g, '')

I believe javascript speaks in UTF-16, so yeah. This has removed the emoji garbage from some free form fields in Zendesk (Zendesk does not permit input mask into ticket fields, like order numbers, sadly).